# Rotate all images in a directory that are of a specific geometry

Tags: command-line, desktop-background, image-processing, imagemagick, jpeg

I would like to rotate all images in a directory that are of a specific geometry. Can I use ImageMagick for this? If so could you help me with the code for the command prompt?

Comment: Are these images all of the same type: gif, jpg, png? And what degree of rotation are you interested in?

Comment: They are all jpg and I would like 90 degrees thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should serve your needs:

```
for i in *.jpg
do
if [ $(identify -format "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]\n" "$i") = 1920x1080 ]
then
convert "$i" -rotate 90 "${i%.jpg}_rotated.jpg"
fi
done
```

Simply alter the `1920x1080` setting for *your* desired size and then copy and paste the whole snippet into a Terminal window *in the directory containing your image files*...

**Explanation of the syntax...**

First there is the *structure*:

1. The basis for this code snippet is the `for` loop which finds all `jpg` files in a certain directory:

   ```
   for i in *.jpg
   do
   <Insert command here....>
   done
   ```

   But some *exclusions* have to be made before a command is run and for this we nest a conditional statement using `if`...
2. The second structure is an `if` statement which importantly contains the `test` for the required jpg size:

   ```
   if <Insert test here...>
   then
   <Insert command here...>
   fi
   ```

Next the `for` loop and the `if` statement are nested, and added to the mix is:

1. *The appropriate test*, which searches for jpgs that are of a required size:

   ```
   [ $(identify -format "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]\n" "$i") = 1920x1080 ]
   ```
2. *The appropriate command*, which rotates these jpg files by 90 degrees:

   ```
   convert "$i" -rotate 90 "${i%.jpg}_rotated.jpg"
   ```

And then the Bash magic works :)